# Memory leak in system library

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been working with iPhone application in which I am using sqlite database. I have checked memory leaks in iPad,iPhone 4 and there is none. But the same code shows a memory leak in iPhone-3GS. So:

- If I click on a leak reference, it will show me an unavailable message.
- If I check Hide system library option, it doesn't show me a leak.

I think the following images are enough to understand my question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your second image, if you click the arrow beside the block's address, what does it show you?

Comment: @PhillipMills: Unavailable...